# jQuery datepicker and numeric plugins not functioning despite jquery-ui.js and numeric.js declared properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

Oddly enough I'm not getting an error message, however the jquery `datepicker` function and `numeric` plugin I'm using will not function on either input field they are supposed to be attached to.

This is just a simple create page, so the controller method does nothing but redirect the user to the `Create.cshtml` page.

```
    //
    // GET: /ZipCodeTerritory/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

I'm just starting with this page, so the view is equally as simplistic. Below are the jquery script tags in the shared layout followed by the `Create` page.

**Layout**

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/typeahead.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Create View**

```
@model Monet.Models.ZipCodeTerritory

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.numeric.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/datepicker.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#ZipCode').numeric();
    $('#EndDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
    })
    $('#EffectiveDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
    })
</script>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>ZipCodeTerritory</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ChannelCode)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ChannelCode, new { maxLength = 1 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ChannelCode)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DrmTerrDesc)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DrmTerrDesc, new { maxLength = 30 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DrmTerrDesc)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IndDistrnId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.IndDistrnId, new { maxLength = 3 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IndDistrnId)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StateCode)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StateCode, new { maxLength = 2 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StateCode)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ZipCode)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ZipCode, new { maxLength = 9 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ZipCode)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDate)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EffectiveDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EffectiveDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EffectiveDate)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastUpdateId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastUpdateId, new { maxLength = 8 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastUpdateId)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Here is the rendered HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#ZipCode').numeric();
    $('#EndDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
    })
    $('#EffectiveDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
    })
</script>

<form action="/ZipCodeTerritory/Create" method="post">    <fieldset>
        <legend>ZipCodeTerritory</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="ChannelCode">Channel Code</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input id="ChannelCode" maxLength="1" name="ChannelCode" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ChannelCode" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="DrmTerrDesc">DRM Territory Description</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input id="DrmTerrDesc" maxLength="30" name="DrmTerrDesc" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="DrmTerrDesc" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="IndDistrnId">Territory</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input id="IndDistrnId" maxLength="3" name="IndDistrnId" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="IndDistrnId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="StateCode">State Code</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input id="StateCode" maxLength="2" name="StateCode" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="StateCode" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="ZipCode">Zip Code</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input id="ZipCode" maxLength="9" name="ZipCode" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ZipCode" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="EndDate">End Date</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The End Date field is required." id="EndDate" name="EndDate" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="EndDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="EffectiveDate">Effective Date</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Effective Date field is required." id="EffectiveDate" name="EffectiveDate" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="EffectiveDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="LastUpdateId">Last Update ID</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input id="LastUpdateId" maxLength="8" name="LastUpdateId" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="LastUpdateId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<div>
    <a href="/ZipCodeTerritory">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Like I said above, neither the `EndDate` or `EffectiveDate` fields show a calendar when clicked on, and you can enter any value you want in the `ZipCode` input box. Hoping this isn't anything too complicated.

**EDIT**

So it looks like no jquery plugins work, at all. Added the following tags and cannot get the `.mask` to work either. These are the script declarations from the `Create` view

```
    <h2>Create</h2>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.numeric.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/datepicker.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Where are the css and script links in your layout file located? Above or below where your Create.cshtml gets rendered?

Comment: Above. Oddly enough the Index page that links to this create page is has the exact same script declarations (I just copied/pasted from there) in the same place. Works fine on that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By putting these in the `document.ready` function they work now.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ZipCode').numeric();
    $('#EndDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
    })
});
```